# What preposition to use when fitting data?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Do we fit data *with*, *by*, or *as* a linear function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of those: we fit data **to** a function. See the [usage throughout Wolfram Alpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CurveFitting.html), for example.

Comment: I thought of that one as well; what stopped me from including this is that it seemed a bit illogical to me in the sense that fitting data __to__ a function sounds like I'm actually altering the data to fit better.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Ah, I see what you are saying; but native speakers would not interpret it that way, and the language is quite standardized. We say "the curve fits the data" and "we fit data to the curve".

Comment: I see, thanks for [the?] clarification :)

Answer (score 4):

I would say you fit a function or model to the data, rather than the other way around.  Or you find a model that fits the data.

Comment: Very nice answer! It is grammatically and contextually correct. And I actually smiled after reading the second sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of weird for me to say "fit data to a function". I don't think there is a big difference either way, but I prefer "fit a function to the data" and I think this latter way is the form I've always heard or read.

I think of it like how a tailor "fits" a dress or suite to a person's body, where the measurements are the data and the clothing piece is the function.

Comment: [I also said that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186544/what-preposition-to-use-when-fitting-data#comment430527_186544) :)

Comment: @JenniferDylan Can you post a cross-reference to this question on mathSE, thanks.

Comment: @Kris it's linked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186544/what-preposition-to-use-when-fitting-data).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't *do* anything to data, which is the point to note.

You could say 'the data *obeys*/ *conforms to*/ or even *fits*, a (linear) function.'

It's important to note the difference between the inherent nature of the data and actions performed on the data.